# dataclassesdatacontext' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my DBML Designer Code

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;



public partial class DataClassesDataContext  : System.Data.Linq.DataContext 

{

    private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

  #region Extensibility Method Definitions
  partial void OnCreated();
  #endregion

    public DataClassesDataContext(string connection) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)

    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public DataClassesDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public DataClassesDataContext(string connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    public DataClassesDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
            base(connection, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

}
```

this is my C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Linq;



public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void cmdLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

    }
}
```

when i write the DataClassesDataContex db=new DataClassesDataContex(); it will show DataClassesDataContex does not  contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments?

Comment: Look at the DataClassesDataContext - unless you have another file with a partial class with additional constructors, I don't see any parameterless constructors.

Comment: then what should i do ?

Comment: Umm....use one of the four constructors provided by the DataClassesDataContext?

Comment: @AshokBhanwal: You provide arguments to the constructor. If you're not sure how to do that, I would step away from LINQ for the moment and learn the core parts of C# - trying to learn LINQ to SQL and ASP.NET without a good grounding in C# is going to be very difficult.

Comment: Your DBML Designer Code is very poor. Where is your OnCreate() method?       @Jon Skeet, I agree with you

Comment: hello guys if you dont know correct answer then leave it coz that same code work fine in visual studio 2008?

Comment: The answers you were given are correct based on the code you posted.  There is no constructor in the posted code that takes 0 arguments.  I would expect the exact same error in 2008 from the above code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no parameterless constructor defined in your class `DataClassesDataContext`. By default there should be another constructor generated, which gets connection string from application settings:

```
public DataClassesDataContext() : 
        base(global::Foo.Properties.Settings.Default.BarConnectionString,
            mappingSource)
{
    OnCreated();
}
```

But for some reason it is missing right now. You can:

- Try to re-generate your data context (possibly you deleted this constructor by mistake). To do this right-click your *dbml* file and select *Run custom tool*.
- Create partial class `DataClassesDataContext` and add parameterless constructor manually
- Pass connection string to constructor when creating context instance

Comment: I eventually solved this issue by going into the dbml, right click>view code (or f7) then adding this constructor to the partial class in this new file

Answer (score 4):

Steps:

1. Remember your dbml file name and delete your dbml file.
2. Then add a new dbml file with the same previous name to the same location (add -> add new Item -> LINQ to SQL Classes).
3. Double click on the dbml file in the Solution Explorer.
4. Now Drag and drop all the tables to that layout of dbml.
5. Finally add all the associations with the tables as previously you have done.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with these steps:

1. Remove your "dataclasses.dbml"
2. Open your "Web.Config"
3. Remove:

   ```
   <connectionString>
       <add name="exampleDB" connectionString="Data Source=example;Initial
       Catalog=example;Integrated Security=True"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
   ```
4. Remove:

   ```
   <assemblies>
       <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
       PublicKeyToken=D...8"/>
   </assemblies>
   ```

You can find `<assemblies>` within `<compilation></compilation>`

If you have more than one `<add assembly />` tag, you have more than one connection to DB.

4. Add another "example.dbml" add your tables again.
5. Create a new datacontext object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Connection setting in the Properties window got removed.

[image: 'DataClassesDataContext' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments]

To see these properties

1. Open the DBML file
2. Click in the DBML File on the white space (not the table definition)
3. Click from the menu View > Properties Window (F4)
4. Scroll down to the Data section. Expand Connection. Click the white space to the right of Connection. Click the drop-down arrow. Your Connection String name from web.config or app.config should appear here.
5. Click it twice to select it.
6. Save
7. Rebuild (ctrl+shift+b) and your default DataClassesDataContext constructor will now work again! :-)

See in the previously attached image that the Connection property got removed.
If you can't readd the Connection, you can revert your source control to a previous history point and just re-add the tables and settings since your last commit.

Problem fixed!

[image: Connection properly reestablished!]

The default constructor in .designer.cs got restored.

```
public DataClassesHelpTicketsDataContext() : 
            base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Help_TicketsConnectionString1"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
```